# Does my server have software RAID 1 set up?

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid

I recently got my dedicated server it has 2x 1TB HDD's, so I asked for software RAID 1 on set-up and my provider asured that server have RAID 1 (software). I tought that if I will run RAID 1, I will have only 1TB of HDD avaible on that server, it seems i have 1,79TB avaible, which makes me think they did not setted it up correctly.

**And the main question is now:** *How can I check if I do run any kind of software RAID within CentOS, with a command over SSH?*

Output of command "mount":

```
[root@saturn ~]# mount
/dev/mapper/isw_bhicgbideg_Volume0p1 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/mapper/isw_bhicgbideg_Volume0p3 on /vz type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
```

Output of command "df -h":

```
[root@saturn ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/isw_bhicgbideg_Volume0p1
                      9.5G  1.4G  7.6G  16% /
/dev/mapper/isw_bhicgbideg_Volume0p3
                      1.8T  3.6G  1.7T   1% /vz
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
```

Output of command "fdisk -l"

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1275    10241406   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            1276        3570    18434587+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            3571      243200  1924827975   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1        1275    10241406   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2            1276        3570    18434587+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3            3571      243200  1924827975   83  Linux
```

OR is it possible that I have 2x 2TB HDD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat /proc/mdstat` will tell you if you're on linux software RAID.

Looks like LVM on top of that - check the display commands to see what the setup looks like.  `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, `lvdisplay`.

You've got 2x 2TB HDs from that `fdisk` output, not 1TB, so that may be the discrepancy that you're seeing.